# Table of contents in the same notebook

Tags: document-creation

I created TOC programatically using instructions from

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/AuthorTools/tutorial/MakeContents.html

But it created second notebook TOC.nb. Is it possible to create TOC for example at the front of my notebook?

Comment: I meant, at the beginning, before the content, because now it's  in seperate notebook

Comment: Please take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). You can always upvote the answer you find useful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about this package but you can either `NotebookGet` created notebook and `NotebookWrite` boxes in your notebook, or do something like

```
<< AuthorTools`

SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Before, Notebook];

NotebookWrite[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 AuthorTools`MakeContents`MakeContentsNotebook[
    NotebookFileName@EvaluationNotebook[], 
    "Simple"]
 ]
```

Comment: I have tried this answer. The problem is that you do not get the format of contents right. See below my answer...

Answer (score 3):

It is important to notice that the notebook must be saved first to use the functions Paginate and MakeContents

```
<< AuthorTools`

nbkObj = SelectedNotebook[];
Paginate[nbkObj]
contObj = MakeContents[nbkObj, "Book"];
```

I can get the contents in the same notebook with...

```
NotebookWrite[nbkObj, NotebookGet[contObj]]
```

but I am loosing the previous "Book" format.

It seems the problem is how to copy the cells from the TOCNotebook and paste them in the main Notebook. I have tried also

```
 SelectionMove[contObj, All, Notebook]
 NotebookWrite[nbkObj, NotebookRead[contObj]]
```

and even

```
 NotebookWrite[nbkObj, NotebookImport[contObj]]
```

but the content style is lost. Any alternatives to preserve also the style of contents while pasting in the same notebook? I was looking also in SE questions related to how one can copy and past cells from one notebook to another preserving the format. But I cannot find the right answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

"...but the content style is lost." The stylesheet used in the `TOC.nb` file is the `HelpBrowser.nb` file. I have copied `TOCSection`, `TOCSubsection` and `TOCSubsubsection` styles from the `HelpBrowser.nb` file to the style file I use for my writing notebooks. You will note that there is a TabSpacings setting in those styles which controls where the page number is printed.